# Sending facebooks invites to specific facebook ids

Tags: facebook

I'm using the jquery.facebook.multifriend.select to retreive and select a list of facebook friends.

Now I want to send the selected list of facebook ids an invite, but am not sure what to do next...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the multi-friend-selector jquery plugin, if you are then pass pre_selected_friends:[ids] into the constructor, you can look at this example from the plugin's github https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector/blob/master/index.html